# What is the correct method to save non-code related files (reference files/test assets) in a python project?

Tags: git

From a quick look around; most users have everything in their favorite repository system, which is usually git. Although if you have large files (imagine something like a machine learning dataset or test files used to validate your code, like movie files, images or audio files for example for applications that use them), that is not an option.

Is there a standard to save those "non-code related" files somewhere, and still keep a connection to the main git repo? Since you still need to version your changes for those files, you want something that allow you to create a list of checkin, and probably also a sort of way to save comments with those commits, exactly like you would do with git. Probably would make sense to add also a list of metadata related to those files you check in, so you can retrieve info about them.

I saw that some use 3rd party applications that save assets zipped somewhere, like on AWS or dropbox for example, but that is not feasible for traceability and checkin history, so I assume there is a better way to track files in a project that are not exactly related to code, so they do not really belong in git?

Answer (score 1):

> Although if you have large files [...] that is not an option.

This is no longer true, there is Git Large File Storage available now, see:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/

For limitations applicable to free github account see:

https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage

Comment: Thanks, so you are suggesting to use GIT also for files that are not code-related, and that should be fine? I want to point out that I may not be using github; my company may have their own implementation of a git server, so I want to be sure I am setting up my projects in a way that is acceptable

Comment: Yes, but be sure to use LFS. Read on how to initialize LFS storage and how to tell git to use it for some of your files. Also, ask maintainer of your instance of Git server if there is support of LFS turned on on your server.